# Save a file generated by app running on docker to a given path in the host machine

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python app running on a docker container and it generates a pdf file. I want to store the generated pdf file in a given path in the host machine.

I am not sure on how can this be achieved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mount a volume in your container mapped to the desired path in your host

```
docker run -d -v /host/path:/python_app/output your_docker_image
```

Where `/python_app/output` is the path inside the container where your app is writing the pdf file.

Note that `/host/path` should have enough permissions

```
chmod 777 /host/path
```

Answer (score 1):

Use volumes to mount directory in a container to host director:

```
docker run -v /MY/HOST_DIR:/MY/CONTAINER_DIR
```

Your pdf file will be stored in /MY/HOST_DIR on host.