# Writing to host machine from a docker container not working

Tags: python, docker

I've created a docker image which runs a python script and outputs a csv file. I can "SSH" into the container and see that the csv file is there, but I want this csv file to go onto my host machine. How can I do that? I tried using this link but it does not work, the file simply never appears: [Save a file generated by app running on docker to a given path in the host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507929/save-a-file-generated-by-app-running-on-docker-to-a-given-path-in-the-host-machi)

Am I missing something? This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN pip install python-geoip-python3
RUN pip install pyyaml ua-parser user-agents
RUN python logParse.py
```

And I am running this command on my image named "parser":

```
docker run -d -v /Users/dppham/Desktop/logParser:/usr/src/app parser
```

The csv file should be in /Users/dppham/Desktop/logParser, right?

Comment: Is your file generated in `/usr/src/app` inside a container? plus, are you running on windows?

Comment: The csv file that is generated is in the container in the /usr/src/app path. Nope, I'm using Mac

Comment: did you check the logs? and try to run the script manually to see if it throw errors

Comment: does any file get written? if so then it is an application problem not a docker mount problem.
ie `docker run -d -v /Users/dppham/Desktop/logParser:/usr/src/app parser bash -c 'echo hello > hello.txt'`
Can you see hello.txt ?

Comment: A .csv file is written into the container itself, and when I vim the .csv file I can see the right contents. I've tried running this locally on my machine and the .csv file is generated too. And yes, I can see hello.txt